# How to fit a regression line through a specific range of values and not all data on ggscatter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, scatter-plot, lm

I've used the following code to create a scatter plot of the relationship between time (x-axis) and an HDL cholesterol (y-axis). The data are coloured by gender and I would like to fit a regression line only through a specific range of values on the x-axis. My time data range from 20 to 180 days but I only want to fit a regression line through 30-90 days while still showing all the data on the plot. How should I modify the code to achieve that?

````
                    add = "reg.line",                        
                    conf.int = TRUE,                          
                    color = "Sex", alpha=0.5)+     
  stat_cor(aes(color= Sex),method = "spearman")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#9c0d4b", "#7ca0d4"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10,2), limits=c(0,10))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=1.37, linetype="dotted", color = "black")+
  xlab("Time (days)") + ylab("HDL")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 11))``` 

Thanks in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the base R `subset` function in graphs:

```
subset(mtcars, mpg <= 26 & mpg >= 22)
               mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710    22.8   4 108.0 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D     24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.19 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.15 22.90  1  0    4    2
Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3 91 4.43 2.14 16.70  0  1    5    2
```